# How to restore a filegroup from its backup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005

I need guidance on how to restore a file group in Database from the File group backup taken from another same DB server. Is it possible to restore the filegroup by running restore DB for File Group.

I was trying to restoring filegroup from its back up like below

```
RESTORE DATABASE <DBName > FILEGROUP = 'MFG12' FROM DISK = 'E:\MFG12.bak'
  WITH RECOVERY
```

The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing `DBNAME` database.

When I was trying to restore in to same DB , restoring works perfectly,

```
Processed 840976 pages for database 'DB', file 'MFG12_File' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE ... FILE=<name> successfully processed 840976 pages in 59.375 seconds  
(110.654 MB/sec).
```

When I run the Select query against partion of filegroup. it throws error

```
 One of the partitions of index '' for table 'xyz'
 (partition ID 72057594656129024) resides on a filegroup ("MFG12")
 that cannot be accessed because it is offline, restoring,
 or defunct. This may limit the query result
```

When I see status of all file group.

I see one of the File Group MFG 12 has status = "Restoring" , How to set back to Online Mode.

When I try to restore log file also.i get below error

```
The roll forward start point is now at log sequence number (LSN) 66787000000001800001.
Additional roll forward past LSN 66787000000008900001 is required to complete the 
restore sequence”.
```

Please help how do I bring back the missing file group data even though filegroup backup has been taken from another same Database in another server or in the same server DB

Comment: You need to apply differential and/or transaction log backup(s) up to the latest point in time of the database.

Answer (score 3):

1. After you restore the filegroup, you need to take a tail log backup of the restored database .
2. Restore the lastest differential you may have to  with norecovery.
3. Restore all the tlog backups to  with norecovery.
4. Restore the tail log backup from step 1 to  with recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my answer at [Backing up file groups with restore to earlier backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40650/backing-up-file-groups-with-restore-to-earlier-backup/42725#42725)

It has all detailed steps outlined.