# Backing up file groups with restore to earlier backup

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup, restore

I have a task: I have created a database with a filegroup `lamb` that has a few tables.

I need to extract a csv into a table in a filegroup named `lamb` and back up that filegroup.

Then extract another csv file again and back up again.

But I need to be able to restore the first backup.

What is the backup and restore method? Is it possible to restore only the `lamb` filegroup?

Comment: This looks like a question for the DBA site, but it isn't clear what you want to do. Specifically, what does "extract into these tables" mean? Are you asking about [partial backups, or file backups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477(v=sql.110).aspx), or something else?

Answer (score 9):

**What is the backup and restore method?**
It is called [Piece Meal Restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177425.aspx) and unrestored filegroups can be restored at a later time.

**Is it possible to restore only the lamb filegroup?**
Yes it is possible to restore only the lamb filegroup.

Below will show you - how you can do it.

1. Create a database called "FGTest"

   ```
   create database [FGTest] on primary (
   name = N'FGTest'
   ,FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\FGTest.mdf'
   ,SIZE = 3072 KB
   ,FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
   )
   ,FILEGROUP [lamb] (
   name = N'lamb'
   ,-- fileGroup1
   FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\FGTest_2.ndf'
   ,SIZE = 3072 KB
   ,FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
   )
   ,FILEGROUP [lamb1] (
   name = N'lamb1'
   ,-- fileGroup2
   FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\FGTest_3.ndf'
   ,SIZE = 3072 KB
   ,FILEGROWTH = 1024 KB
   ) LOG on (
   name = N'FGTest_log'
   ,FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\DATA\FGTest_log.ldf'
   ,SIZE = 1024 KB
   ,FILEGROWTH = 10 %
   )
   ```

   go
2. Now create tables on different file groups - lamb and lamb1

   ```
   create table TAB1 (
   TAB1_ID int IDENTITY(1, 1)
   ,TAB1_NAME varchar(100)
   ,constraint PK_TAB1 primary key (TAB1_ID)
   ) on lamb -- Filegroup we created.
   go

   create table TAB1_lamb1 (
   TAB1_ID int IDENTITY(1, 1)
   ,TAB1_NAME varchar(100)
   ,constraint PK_TAB1_lamb1 primary key (TAB1_ID)
   ) on lamb1 -- 2nd Filegroup we created.
   go
   ```
3. Take a Base backup

   ```
   -- Take a base backup
   BACKUP DATABASE [FGTest] to 
   DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_basebackup.bak'
   with init, stats = 10
   go
   ```
4. Now insert some values .... You can load a CSV at this point

   ```
   INSERT INTO FGTest..TAB1(TAB1_NAME)
   select ('TAB1')
   union all
   select ('TAB2')
   ```
5. backup filegroup lamb -- with 2 records

   ```
   -- backup filegroup lamb - with 2 records

   BACKUP DATABASE [FGTest] FILEGROUP = N'lamb' 
   TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_2Records.bak' 
   WITH  INIT,  NAME = N'FGTest-Full Filegroup Backup', 
   STATS = 10
   GO

   -- log backup filegroup lamb - with 2 records

   BACKUP LOG [FGTest] TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_2records.trn' WITH INIT
   ```
6. Now insert few more values in lamb and lamb1 file groups

   ```
   INSERT INTO FGTest..TAB1(TAB1_NAME)
   select ('TAB3')
   union all
   select ('TAB4')

   INSERT INTO FGTest..TAB1_lamb1(TAB1_NAME)
   select ('TAB3')
   union all
   select ('TAB4')
   ```
7. Now backup lamb and lamb1 filegroups along with the T-logs

   ```
   -- -- backup filegroup lamb - with 4 records

   BACKUP DATABASE [FGTest] FILEGROUP = N'lamb' 
   TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_4Records.bak' 
   WITH  INIT,  NAME = N'FGTest-Full Filegroup Backup', 
   STATS = 10
   GO

   -- log backup filegroup lamb - with 4 records

   BACKUP LOG [FGTest] TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_4records.trn' WITH INIT 


   -- -- backup filegroup lamb1 - with 2 records

   BACKUP DATABASE [FGTest] FILEGROUP = N'lamb1' 
   TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_lamb1.bak' 
   WITH  INIT,  NAME = N'FGTest-Full Filegroup Backup', 
   STATS = 10
   GO
   ```

   -- log backup filegroup lamb1 - with 2 records

   ```
   BACKUP LOG [FGTest] TO DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_lamb1_log.trn' WITH INIT
   ```

[image]

## Now comes the restore Part :

1. Restore the database with PARTIAL and NORECOVERY

   ```
    use master
    go

    -- restore the base backup with PARTIAL and NORECOVERY

    restore database [FGTest]
    filegroup = 'Primary'
    from disk = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_basebackup.bak'
    with REPLACE, PARTIAL, NORECOVERY
    go
   ```
2. Now Restore the lamb filegroup along with the T-log

   ```
    RESTORE DATABASE [FGTest] FILE = N'lamb' FROM  
    DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_2Records.bak' 
    WITH  FILE = 1, REPLACE,  STATS = 10
    GO

    RESTORE LOG [FGTest] FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQL2008R2\MSSQL\Backup\FGTest_2records.trn'
    WITH FILE = 1, NORECOVERY
   ```

-- since you want to restore the database to 1st backup and you already restored the sequence, its time to bring the database back online with 2 records.

restore database [FGTest] with recovery
[image]

Since you have not brought the other file group online, when you try to query **TAB1_lamb1** table residing on lamb1 filegroup, the query processor will throw an error.

[image]