# Impact of Log backups restore process after file\file group restore on a database

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, backup, filegroups

When we restore file\file group(backup1) backup on a database is it necessary to restore all log backups that were taken after backup1 to get database in consistent state??
and also what will be the impact of log restore process on database state and those files?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 1):

> When we restore file\file group(backup1) backup on a database is it necessary to restore all log backups that were taken after backup1 to get database in consistent state??

Yes - if you want to **completely** bring your database online (with all file groups) or you want to do a point-in-time restore of your database.

No - if you want to do a piece meal restore for specific file group.

I have explained in detail by giving an example at [**Backing up file groups with restore to earlier backup**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42725/8783).

Comment: what I get is, 
1. After restoring file group backup we can restore File Group transnational log\differential backup if we want to recover the file group with enough log to a stable point-in-time state.
2. and Impact of file group transnational log\differential backup restore will effect only the file group on which we are restoring backup and will not effect the other file groups.